# Which SmartTV can open a browser on boot?

Tags: boot, smart-tv

Is there a SmartTV that can open a browser when it's powered on (in EU)? And how can you do it (do you need to hack the TV)?

Answer (score 1):

You can  try some "hack" but it is not so easy. I try it for Samsung models (Without tizen OS). 
I had to enable running ticker applications in Samsung service menu (Any classic system menu in TV) Then you can set ticker app It should be your easy app where you define something like: "Open webbrowser with some URL".

Another not easy way is using TV with Android but I think, you should also implement some app which open webbrowser.

I hope that it for helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

All of Samsung's [SSSP TV](https://displaysolutions.samsung.com/solutions/partner-solution/sssp)'s can do that. But they are expensive.